# All mp3 files in raw folder played

Tags: android, audio

i build a simple app with one layout and two buttons, and this is my code..

```
package com.example.tessound;

import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener
{

MediaPlayer player;
Button play,mute;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    play = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    play.setOnClickListener(this);
    mute = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
    mute.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

public void onClick(View view)
{
    if(view.getId()==R.id.button1)
    {
        playSound(1);
    }
    else if(view.getId()==R.id.button2)
    {
        playSound(2);
    }
}

public void playSound(int arg)
{
    try
    {
        if(player != null)
        {
            if (player.isPlaying()) 
            {
                player.stop();
                player.release();
            }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {

    }

    if (arg == 1)
    {
        player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.atur);
    }
    else if (arg == 2)
    {
        player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.back);
    }

    if(player != null)
    {
        player.setLooping(false);
        player.start();
    }

    }
}
```

My raw folder contains:
atur.mp3, back.mp3, belajar.mp3, level.mp3, skip.mp3, and start.mp3...
While i click button mute, back.mp3 is played, but when i click button play, all of the mp3 in raw folder is played.. Any comments?

Comment: wts ur problem at first place ?

Answer (score 0):

I have copied your code and tested it. In my system it's work fine. I have just rename the songs and button id , because those raw songs I can't get. Please look this code, the code is same, because I just copied this code:

```
package com.mukherjee.satyaki.test;

import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity1 extends Activity implements OnClickListener
{

MediaPlayer player;
Button play,mute;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    play = (Button)findViewById(R.id.songid1);
    play.setOnClickListener(this);
    mute = (Button)findViewById(R.id.songid2);
    mute.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

public void onClick(View view)
{
    if(view.getId()==R.id.songid1)
    {
        playSound(1);
    }
    else if(view.getId()==R.id.songid2)
    {
        playSound(2);
    }
}

public void playSound(int arg)
{
    try
    {
        if(player != null)
        {
            if (player.isPlaying()) 
            {
                player.stop();
                player.release();
            }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {

    }

    if (arg == 1)
    {
        player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.ram1);
    }
    else if (arg == 2)
    {
        player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.ram3);
    }

    if(player != null)
    {
        player.setLooping(false);
        player.start();
    }

    }
}
```

You code is fine, as per my earlier assumption restart the emulator and wipe user data and then tests. I think the problem will be solved by your code.

Thanks.

Comment: i have restarted the emulator, clean, wipe user data, and it still played all the mp3 while i choose atur.mp3, level.mp3, skip.mp3.. when i choose back.mp3, belajar.mp3, and start.mp3, there was no problem.. :|

Comment: But my dear friend I have used your code, it's give perfect result. Now I have no idea about this. Sorry friend.

Answer (score 0):

I remember having a similar issue, my code ended up looking like this:

```
if (!getmMediaPlayer().isPlaying()) {
    try {
        AssetFileDescriptor fd = getResources().openRawResourceFd(
                R.raw.snooze);
        getmMediaPlayer().setDataSource(fd.getFileDescriptor(),
                fd.getStartOffset(), fd.getLength());
        getmMediaPlayer().setAudioStreamType(
                AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM);
        getmMediaPlayer().setLooping(true);
        getmMediaPlayer().prepare();
        getmMediaPlayer().start();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
    }
}
```

Specifically I believe it was the setDataSource that was important.